# Error: Could not find a production build in the '/app/.next' directory. Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the production server

Tags: docker, next.js

Encountered this problem while trying to dockerize a nextjs application.

```
Error: Could not find a production build in the '/app/.next' directory. Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the production server
```

Here's the Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14-alpine3.14 as deps

ARG NEXT_PUBLIC_PRODUCTION_ENDPOINT
ARG NEXT_PUBLIC_PAGE
ARG NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_KEY
ARG SCHEMA_ENDPOINT

RUN apk add --no-cache tini
ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/tini", "--"]
EXPOSE 4500
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat

RUN mkdir /app && chown -R node:node /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY --chown=node:node package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install && npm cache clean --force

FROM node:14-alpine3.14 as build
RUN mkdir /app && chown -R node:node /app
WORKDIR /app
ENV NODE_ENV=production
COPY --chown=node:node . ./
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
RUN npm run build

FROM node:14-alpine3.14 as prod
RUN mkdir /app && chown -R node:node /app
WORKDIR /app
ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV PORT=7777
COPY --chown=node:node package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci --production && npm cache clean --force
COPY --from=build /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=build /app/next.config.js ./
USER node
CMD ["node_modules/.bin/next", "start"]
```

and here's the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  playgames-frontend:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    environment:
      - NEXT_PUBLIC_PRODUCTION_ENDPOINT=${NEXT_PUBLIC_PRODUCTION_ENDPOINT}
      - NEXT_PUBLIC_PAGE=${NEXT_PUBLIC_PAGE}
      - NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_KEY=${NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_KEY}
      - SCHEMA_ENDPOINT=${SCHEMA_ENDPOINT}
```

I've split up the dockerfile into multiple stages since I need both dependencies because I'm using typescript.

I'm copying the `.next` folder after building it during the build step with `COPY --from=build /app/.next ./.next`

The image is being built successfully but when I try to run the container I get the error. The image should have the `.next` folder.

Image history also has `COPY /app/.next ./.next # buildkit`

Comment: Your Dockerfile block has `volumes:` that overwrite absolutely everything in the image's `/app` directory; you're not really using your image at all, and just running Node on the host might be easier if you're trying to directly run the host code.  If you delete the `volumes:` block from the Compose file, does the Docker-packaged application work better?

Comment: Yes that solves the issue. I see so the problem was the volumes overwriting the images directory. I wasn't aware of this behavior of `volumes`.  `just running Node on the host might be easier if you're trying to directly run the host code` yeah it's easier and was what I was previously doing as well but since I'm currently studying docker I was trying to deploy it using containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should delete the `volumes:` block from your Compose file.

When the Compose file says

```yaml
volumes:
  - ./:/app
  - /app/node_modules
```

this tells Docker two things: first, that the entire `/app` directory from the image should be replaced with contents from the host system; and second, on top of that, the `node_modules` directory contains user data that needs to be stored in an anonymous volume and persisted.

The consequence of this is that, with this `volumes:` block, nothing you do in your Dockerfile is used at all.  Even though you explicitly `COPY` a `.next` directory into the final image, at runtime everything in `/app` – including `/app/.next` – is hidden and replaced with the host directory.  If there happens to be a `.next` directory on the host, things might work, but if not, you'll get the error you see.

Deleting this `volumes:` block means that you'll actually use the code that's built into the image.  If you're using Docker because you eventually plan to use it for deployment, it means you're running the code and filesystem layout that will be used in production.  A workflow I typically use is to use host tools, in this case unmodified non-Docker Node, for day-to-day development, and only bring Docker into the picture when I want to do final integration testing and deployment.